Extract the name from the project via T4 template without using DTE
I need to find the name of the project in which the tt file is located using a t4 template with C#.
I don't want to use DTE because I had a couple of errors that I couldn't resolve.
I would have found this solution
string NameProject = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(TargetPath)"));

but when I execute this instruction in "Dubug T4 Template" I can extract the name of the project while when I carry out a Rebuild of the entire solution in the string I get $(TargetPath).
